# Count characters in anchor and resize it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a script that counts the number of characters in an anchor tag inside a list item and, if the number of characters is higher than 18, makes the anchor tag narrower so that the text will break. Here's what I have so far, but it's not working. Help?

```
        $('nav li a').each(function() {
            var curr = this.text().length();
            if(curr >= 18){
                this.width(50);
            }
        });
```

Oh, and for bonus points: is there some way to make the text on the second line indent after the anchor shrinks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this instead:

```
    $('nav li a').each(function() {
        var curr = $(this).text().length;
        if(curr >= 18){
            $(this).width(50);
        }
    });
```

Comment: $(this).width(50); // this needs wrapper too =)

Comment: I hadn't noticed the perens after length until your post.

Comment: @Headshota That did it! Plus @zzzzBov's comment below. :)

Comment: @qp2wd your welcome. now i see that you havent accepted much of the answers to ur Q's, people are more likely to help u on future Q's if u accept answers the the Q's u already asked ^_^

Comment: @Neal Sadly, most of my questions never get successful answers. I end up plowing away at things until I figure it out myself. If I do get a correct answer, though, I'm happy to accept them.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark:

You probably didn't set the anchor's display to `block` or `inline-block`.

Alternatively, you've got a particularly long word, which will not break automatically unless you add some `<wbr>`s. Quirksmode has [a nice page about wordbreaks](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html)

Comment: Yup, forgot to set display:block in the css. Doy! Oooh, I've never heard of `<wbr>` before. I can't use it in this case since the links in question are being dynamically generated by my CMS, but I'll keep it in mind for the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're missing a character from your *nav* selector - either a . or a #

For your second point about indenting the second line, try this:

```
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;    
}
```

Comment: the OP is not missing anything. nav is an html tag: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_nav.asp

Comment: So it is. Not had much of a chance to play with HTML 5 yet. Every day is a school day :)

Comment: Yup, the second line tip worked great! Thanks so much. :) As for HTML5, I love it. It saves me from having to create a jillion IDs/classes.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few little glitches here.

- You have to do everything after the
  page loads, so something like
  $(document).ready(...) would be
  necessary.
- The each function doesn't
  work quite like you had it, it takes
  two parameters that you can then work
  with.
- And lastly, the anchor tag is
  an inline tag, so it has no width. 
  For what you want to work you'd need
  to either style your a tags with
  `display: block` or `display:
  inline-block`, or just use a different
  container.

So this would work with the text directly in the list item for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').each(function(index, listItem) {
        var curr = $(listItem).text().length;
        if(curr >= 18){
            $(listItem).width(50);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It was wrapped in a doc ready tag, I just excluded it in the posted example. The whole thing's working now. Thanks!

Comment: No, thank you.  I learned the alternate syntax for the each function.  So I guess I was wrong above.